# Is there a way to two-way bind jqxComboBox?

Tags: angular, jqwidget, two-way-binding, jqxcombobox

Here is my form:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <jqxComboBox [source]="source" formControlName="control">
    </jqxComboBox>
  </form>
```

I'm trying to update it from code behind like this:

```
this.form.get("control").setValue(value);
```

It works with `jqxInput` but not with `jqxComboBox`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this library so I did a short research and I guess you should use `[selectedIndex]` attribute for that

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <jqxComboBox [source]="source" formControlName="control" [selectedIndex]="index">
  </jqxComboBox>
</form>
```

And then in `.ts` file you can set it to index of the value in your source

```
public setValue(): void {
  this.index = this.source.findIndex(val => val === 'desiredValue');
}
```